# Quero desativar todos os botões de hardware impedir a saída do aplicativo

Tags: ionic3

O que preciso fazer é desativar os botões de hardware do Android (usando o Ionic), para impedir que o aplicativo seja fechado, impedir voltar à página principal do Android ou sair do aplicativo de qualquer maneira.

Quero desativar os botões back, home e o botão de tarefas, se possível, o botão que bloqueia o dispositivo também.

É possível?

Preciso disso para um formulário de registro (um dispositivo para o público em uma loja). Não quero que as pessoas fechem o aplicativo ou acessem o menu do Android de forma alguma

Comment: Veja os links que o @AristoEinstein indicou, isso que você procura é chamado modo Quiosque(Kiosk). Tem esse link também: [Dedicated devices cookbook](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/cookbook?hl=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da uma olhada no modo Kiosk do Android acho que é o que você precisa https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices.

Se for isso mesmo, o Cordova possui um [plugin](https://github.com/hkalina/cordova-plugin-kiosk) que faz isso.

Um plugin Cordova para criar um aplicativo com o "modo de quiosque". Um aplicativo com este plug-in pode ser definido como um iniciador do Android. Ele bloqueia os botões de hardware e a barra de status, para que o usuário não possa fechá-lo até que ele seja solicitado.